# Choosing locative preposition: Il fait froid __ montagne/ville/mer

Tags: choix-de-mot, prépositions, indications-de-lieu

I am troubling with French locative prepositions.

When I want to talk about the overall environment of an area, like *il fait froid/chaud*, *il y a du soleil*, how can I know which preposition to use?

> Il fait froid en montagne / ... à la montagne / dans la montagne.

Which is(/are) correct? What is the difference if any two of them are correct?

- I saw some on a random website say *dans la montagne* means "inside the mountain", which hardly make sense.
- *en ville* seems to be the most common collocation for *ville*, is *dans la* or *à la* also work if I am talking about the environment?
- How about the case of *mer* or nouns for other similar places?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most alternatives are possible, sometimes with different meanings.

> Il fait froid en montagne.
> Il fait froid à la montagne.
> Il fait froid dans la montagne.

> Il fait froid en ville.
> Il fait froid dans la ville.

> Il fait froid en mer.
> Il fait froid à la mer.
> Il fait froid dans la mer.

*En montagne* and *à la montagne* tend to be more generic than *dans la montagne*. There is no problem with saying the latter which doesn't necessarily mean *inside the mountain* but more generally *inside the area where the mountain is*.

I don't list *à la ville* because it sounds like "rural French" to my ears.

*Dans la mer* means in the water, *à la mer* often means at the seaside while *en mer* means *au large* (offshore).